# Error When using Azure Media Services SDK With Owin Self Hosted Web API

Tags: asp.net, azure, owin, katana, azure-media-services

I'm trying to setup an existing Web API project to use OWIN Self-Host similar to:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

I'm facing a problem related to Windows Azure Media Service SDK. When I try to call the following method in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.CloudMediaContext:

```
_context = new CloudMediaContext(credentials);
var account = _context.StorageAccounts.Where(obj => obj.Name == "accountName").FirstOrDefault() //error
```

I get back the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233069
>     Message=Method not found: 'Microsoft.Data.OData.IODataRequestMessage System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs.get_RequestMessage()'.
>     Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client
>     StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.OAuth.OAuthDataServiceAdapter.OnSendingRequest(Object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
>          at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.FireSendingRequest2(SendingRequest2EventArgs eventArgs)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.RequestInfo.FireSendingRequest2(SendingRequest2EventArgs eventArgs)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper.FireSendingRequest2(Descriptor descriptor)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.CreateExecuteResult(Object source, DataServiceContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, String method)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
>          at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.MediaQueryProvider`1.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>          at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>          at MediaCloud.Azure.Stores.Azure.AzureMediaService.GetStorageAccounts(String[] storageAccounts) in AzureMediaService.cs:line 239
>          at MediaCloud.Azure.Stores.Azure.AzureMediaService..ctor(String mediaSvcAccountName, String mediaSvcAccountKey, String inputAccounts, String outputAccounts) in AzureMediaService.cs:line 78
>          at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext )
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
>     InnerException:

I guess my question is: Does Azure Media Service SDK supports this self-hosting scenario or not and whether there is any workarounds for this situation.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, azure media services .net sdk should work in Owin based self hosted API's. If you still have issues please let me know in which datacenter you having this exception and i will try to diagnose it.

Comment: Hi George I'm not working on this project now, however I informed my former colleagues and they will get back to you if they still having this issue. Thanks